# How to use wildcards for directories with leading zeros in their names in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Mentioned some weird behavior in using spark read function:

```
 spark.read.json(".../date=2019-08-0[1-9]")//works
 spark.read.json(".../date=2019-08-[10-20]")//throws "Path does not exist" but folders definetily exist.
 spark.read.json(".../date=2019-08-{10,11,12,13}")//works
 spark.read.json(".../date=2019-08-[01-10]")// throws java.io.IOException: Illegal file pattern: Illegal character range near index n
```

How to wildcarding range with leading zeros?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Hadoop Glob Pattern](https://hail.is/docs/0.1/hadoop_glob_patterns.html)

- `[abc]`: Matches a single character from character set {a,b,c}
- `[a-b]`: Matches a single character from the character range {a…b}
- `{ab,cd}`: Matches a string from the string set {ab, cd}

So, `[10-20]` matches one of {1, 0~2, 0}.

`date=2019-08-[10-20]` equals to `date=2019-08-{0,1,2}`, probably there are no such files.